# Projective Transformations: "If all the points lie on a plane, then the linear mapping reduces to ..."

Tags: geometry, transformation, projective-geometry, projective-space, computer-vision

Page 7 of my computer vision textbook, *Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision*, says the following:

> In applying projective geometry to the imaging process, it is customary to model the world as a $3$D projective space, equal to $\mathbb{R}^3$ along with points at infinity. Similarly the model for the image is the $2$D projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$. Central projection is simply a map from $\mathbb{P}^3$ to $\mathbb{P}^2$. If we consider points in $\mathbb{P}^3$ written in terms of homogeneous coordinates $(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y}, \mathrm{Z}, \mathrm{T})^T$ and let the centre of projection be the origin $(0, 0, 0, 1)^T$, then we see that the set of all points $(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y}, \mathrm{Z}, \mathrm{T})^T$ for fixed $\mathrm{X}$, $\mathrm{Y}$, and $\mathrm{Z}$, but varying $\mathrm{T}$ form a single ray passing through the point centre of projection, and hence all mapping to the same point. Thus, the final coordinates of $(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y}, \mathrm{Z}, \mathrm{T})$ is irrelevant to where the point is imaged. In fact, the image point is the point in $\mathbb{P}^2$ with homogeneous coordinates $(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y}, \mathrm{Z})^T$. Thus, the mapping may be represented by a mapping of $3$D homogeneous coordinates, represented by a $3 \times 4$ matrix $\mathrm{P}$ with the block structure $P = [I_{3 \times 3} | \mathbf{0}_3]$, where $I_{3 \times 3}$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix and $\mathbf{0}_3$ a zero 3-vector. Making allowance for a different centre of projection, and a different projective coordinate frame in the image, it turns out that the most general imaging projection is represented by an arbitrary $3 \times 4$ matrix of rank $3$, acting on the homogeneous coordinates of the point in $\mathbb{P}^3$ mapping it to the imaged point in $\mathbb{P}^2$. This matrix $\mathrm{P}$ is known as the camera matrix.
>
> In summary, the action of a projective camera on a point in space may be expressed in terms of a linear mapping of homogeneous coordinates as
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}
> x \\
> y \\
> w \end{bmatrix} = \mathrm{P}_{3 \times 4}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \mathrm{X} \\
> \mathrm{Y} \\
> \mathrm{Z} \\
> \mathrm{T} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Furthermore, if all the points lie on a plane (we may choose this as the plane $\mathrm{Z} = 0$) then the linear mapping reduces to
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}
> x \\
> y \\
> w \end{bmatrix} = \mathrm{H}_{3 \times 3}
> \begin{bmatrix}
> \mathrm{X} \\
> \mathrm{Y} \\
> \mathrm{T} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> which is a projective transformation.

The aforementioned section of the textbook is available freely [here](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZintroduction.pdf).

My questions are as follows:

1. Where it says

> Thus, the final coordinates of $(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y}, \mathrm{Z}, \mathrm{T})$ is irrelevant to where the point is imaged.

shouldn't the vector be $(\mathrm{X}, \mathrm{Y}, \mathrm{Z}, \mathrm{T})^T$?

2. What is $\mathrm{H}_{3 \times 3}$ supposed to be?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It really doesn't make a difference whether you think of it as a row or column vector. I suppose if you're being consistent, yes, it's still the column vector $(X,Y,Z,T)^\top$, but clearly the final component of $(X,Y,Z,T)^\top$ is the same as the final coordinate of $(X,Y,Z,T)$.

2) "the most general imaging projection is represented by an arbitrary 3×4 matrix of rank 3, acting on the homogeneous coordinates of the point in $\mathbb{P}^3$ mapping it to the imaged point in $\mathbb{P}^2$. This matrix $P$ is known as the camera matrix."

So if $P$ is arbitrary of rank 3, and we are imposing the linear condition $Z = 0$, $P$ will reduce to a matrix $H$ that is simply $P$ with the 3rd column removed. This may have rank 2 or 3. Try it out for yourself, constructing examples of matrices $P$.

Comment: I don’t understand why the linear condition $\mathrm{Z} = 0$ will remove the 3rd column? Please elaborate.

Comment: @ThePointer Think harder about how matrix multiplication works.

Comment: @amd But why does the transformation become $$\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
w \end{bmatrix} = \mathrm{H}_{3 \times 3}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{X} \\
\mathrm{Y} \\
\mathrm{T} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$ instead of $$\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
w \end{bmatrix} = \mathrm{P}_{3 \times 4}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathrm{X} \\
\mathrm{Y} \\
0 \\
\mathrm{T} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$?

Comment: That's what I mean when I say I don't see why having $\mathrm{Z} = 0$ necessitates getting rid of the entire 3rd column.

Comment: @ThePointer $H$ is a map (homography) between two planes. Homogeneous coordinate vectors on the planes only have three components. You could just as well have chosen _any_ plane in the ambient projective space and a coordinate system for that plane, as is explained elsewhere in the book.